# MySQL select over the result set again

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Edit (for clarification): Hannes wants to search records with a certain VID and associated records from the same table with the condition AID (from original records) = TID.

EDIT, because wrog problem description (sorry for that!)

I need a query in MySQL that loops through the selected rows and creates a result array. The pattern for this is shown below.

Currently I call a select again and again. Is there a way to create a single query from this? Thanks a lot!

Table structure

ID, VID, AID, ... (title, etc.) ... TID

1. Select over the vid field

`SELECT id, vid, aid FROM tbl WHERE vid = 24;`

```
ID  VID AID
1   24  NULL
2   24  NULL
3   24  712
4   24  713
5   24  714
6   24  715
7   24  716
...
```

2. If aid not null => select the same table with the AID value as condition for another field

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE TID = 112
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE TID = 113 
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE TID = 114 
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE TID = 115 
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE TID = 116
```

3. Result should be (all null rows and the selected rows from above)

```
ID  VID AID   ...
1   24  NULL
2   24  NULL
75  24  712
79  24  713
88  24  714
92  24  715
97  24  716
```

The problem in this e.g. is that i need a loop and tones of selects. Pseudocode:

```
rows = [] 
foreach (main_select)
{
    if (aid != null)
    {
        selected_row = select * from tbl where tid = aid
        rows[] = selected_row
    }
    else
    {
        rows[] = main_select_row_from_iteration
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do all of that with a single query

```
SELECT tbl1.ID as TBL1_ID, tbl1.VID as TBL1_VID, tbl1.AID as TBL1_AID,
       tbl2.ID as TBL2_ID, tbl2.VID as TBL2_VID, tbl2.AID as TBL2_AID 
FROM tbl AS tbl1
LEFT JOIN tbl AS tbl2 ON tbl1.AID = tbl2.TID
WHERE tbl1.VID = 24 AND tbl1.AID IS NOT NULL
```

It's a self-join of the same table, the WHERE condition makes sure that you have the initial VID and that there's not NULL value in AID. The JOIN takes AID and matches it to TID.

The fields in the SELECT list are from both, separated via alias.

Comment: Hello, thank you! This works. I need one adjustment. for multiple results only the first hit should be collected. working e.g. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/67dbdb/4

Comment: Ok, i can add distinct .. thank you again.

Comment: @Honk If you understand this question please clean it up with an edit so that it becomes more helpful to future readers.  I don't understand the question.